# Java Nested If statements - where do brackets go

Tags: java, if-statement

Where should my curly braces go in the structure below?
I am getting an `error: 'else' without 'if'`

```
if

    if

    else if

    else

else if

    if 

    else

else
```

Comment: I can see a couple of different possibilities, not sure which is right. Could you provide more code, i.e. what the `if` conditions are checking?

Comment: The bracketing you need is strongly implied by the nesting you have there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement nested if using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597696/how-to-implement-nested-if-using-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (){
    if (){
    }
    else if (){
    }
    else (){
    }
} else if (){
    if  (){
    }
    else (){
    }
} else (){
}
```

Comment: Block of code with no explanations is a bad answer. It's also wrong: what is `else ()`? How you got 3 upvotes for this is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Learn Java.
Here is a link to the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Step 2: The brackets go everywhere.

```
if (blam)
{
}
else if (kapow)
{
}
else
{
}
```